# Factorization in formal power series versus in convergent power series over the complexes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, cv.complex-variables

Let $R=\mathbb C\{x_1,...,x_n\}\subset S=\mathbb C [[x_1,...,x_n]]$ denote the ring of convergent, respectively formal, power series over $\mathbb C$.
Suppose $f\in R$ is irreducible in $R$. Does it remain irreducible in $S$?

Comment: When crossposting, it's important to link all versions together to avoid duplication of work. [Here is the post on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3809316/factorization-in-formal-power-series-versus-in-convergent-power-series-over-the).

Comment: What partial results do you know of? I think Nagata proved this for prime instead of irreducible.

Comment: The ring of germs of holomorphic functions is a UFD (see section 2.2 of http://people.math.harvard.edu/~yifei/Weierstrass_theorems.pdf . I think I remember this being in Gunning and Rossi, but I can't find my copy right now.) So prime = irreducible. Does this finish the question?

Comment: Right, but Arno Fehm then says that Nagata proved this with prime in place of irreducible.

Comment: Okay, I communicated badly somewhere. What someone should do now is to track down the Nagata paper and track down the UFD fact to canonical references, and check that I am not missing some other logic. I haven't  posted an answer because I haven't done that work. I agree that someone should do it.

Comment: I do find the comments of the OP quite rude. That said, I *think* that prime elements stay prime because Nagata claims that prime ideals stay prime in the introduction to his 1953 paper "Some remarks on local rings, II", but I haven't actually looked into the proofs.

Comment: @ArnoFehm Thank you very much for the reference!

Comment: Thank you @David for going through the details!

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: You were right about Gunning and Rossi: https://books.google.co.vi/books?id=wsqFAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA65#v=onepage&q&f=false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Arno Fehm points out, this follows from results in Nagata's [Some Remarks on Local Rings II](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.kjm/1250777424). Both $R$ and $S$ are UFD's, so $f$ is irreducible, in $R$ or $S$ respectively, if and only if the ideal it generates, in $R$ or $S$ respectively, is prime. At the bottom of page 1 of Nagata's paper, he states that, if $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of $R$, then $\mathfrak{p}S$ is prime as well.

I found it hard to absorb all of Nagata's vocabulary; here is a route to get the desired claim from his results while skipping some of the sophisticated language.

Let $R'$ and $S'$ denote the versions of $R$ and $S$ with $n-1$ variables. Suppose that $f=gh$ for $f \in R$ and $g$, $h \in S$ nonunits. Use the [Weierstrass preparation theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Weierstrass+preparation+theorem) to factor $f = pu$, $g=qv$ and $h = rw$ where $p \in R'[x_n]$, $q \in S'[x_n]$ and $r \in S'[x_n]$ are [Weierstrass polynomials](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Weierstrass+preparation+theorem#weierstrass_polynomial) and $u \in R^{\times}$, $v \in S^{\times}$ and $w \in S^{\times}$ are units. Then $qr$ is a Weierstrass polynomial of $S$, and $vw \in S^{\times}$, so $f = (qr) (vw)$ and $f = pu$ are both Weierstrass factorizations in $S$. Since such factorizations are unique, we have $p = qr$ and $u = vw$.

Write $p(x_n) = x_n^a + \sum_{i=0}^{a-1} p_i x_n^i$, $q(x_n) = x_n^b + \sum_{i=0}^{a-1} q_i x_n^i$, $r(x_n) = x_n^c + \sum_{i=0}^{c-1} r_i x_n^i$. Then the $q_i$ and $r_i$ are polynomial combinations of the roots of $p$, so the $q_i$ and $r_i$ are integral over $R'$. But Nagata, in his proof of Theorem 5, shows that $R'$ is integrally closed in $S'$, and this proof is extremely concrete. So that shows that the $q_i$ and $r_i$ land in $R'$. Thus $q$ and $r \in R$, and we deduce that $f$ factors in $R$ as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your remarkable work, David. Your extracting an answer to my question so quickly from Nagata's hard to read aricle (and idiosyncratic terminology) is a real *tour de force" .